# Slow subset and plot function in R is there an obvious more optimal way to do this?

Tags: r, performance, function, optimization

I am rather new to R and I wrote the following function to try and automate data analysis but it is awfully slow and I feel like I am not going about this the best way. 
My code is as follows:

```
traces<-function(list){
    for(i in seq(list)){ ##iterate over each dataset that was uploaded
            ##subset of data containing only current and time info by looking for pA and Time patterns in variable name
            current<-subset(list[[i]],grepl('pA',list[[i]]$variable)==TRUE|grepl('Time',list[[i]]$variable)==TRUE) 
            ##create a plot of current vs time
            currentPlot<-ggplot(current, aes(Time..s.,value, group = variable)) + 
                    geom_line() +
                    xlim(c(0.2,0.4)) +
                    xlab("") +
                    ylim(c(-500,10000)) +
                    ylab("Current (pA)") +
                    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
                    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
                            axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16, face='bold'))
            ##subset of data containing only voltage and time info by looking for mV and Time patterns in variable name
            voltage<-subset(list[[i]],grepl('mV',list[[i]]$variable)==TRUE|grepl('Time',list[[i]]$variable)==TRUE)
            ##create a plot of voltage vs time
            voltagePlot<-ggplot(voltage, aes(Time..s.,value, group = variable)) + 
                    geom_line() +
                    xlim(c(0.2,0.4)) +
                    xlab("Time (s)") +
                    ylab("Voltage (mV)") +
                    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
                    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                          panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
                          axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16, face='bold'))

            grid.arrange(currentPlot,voltagePlot, ncol=1)
    }
```

A previous function uploads all the files within a given directory and creates a list of each data frame then melts each data frame so that the data appears in the following format:

```
   Time..s.      variable   value
1   0.00000 Trace..1..pA. 89.7217
2   0.00005 Trace..1..pA. 79.9561
3   0.00010 Trace..1..pA. 76.2939
4   0.00015 Trace..1..pA. 90.9424
5   0.00020 Trace..1..pA. 90.9424
6   0.00025 Trace..1..pA. 89.7217
7   0.00030 Trace..1..pA. 72.0215
8   0.00035 Trace..1..pA. 85.4492
9   0.00040 Trace..1..pA. 76.9043
10  0.00045 Trace..1..pA. 76.2939
```

The number of lines is 220000 per each block of data

When I run microbenchmark the program is taking roughly half a minute to get through 5 of these files on average:

```
Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 traces(data) 21.50022 24.16457 28.0191 25.88923 29.72424 40.81457    10
```

I read that loops aren't the fastest method to begin with but I don't see an easy way around it.

Let me know if there's anything obvious I was missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Mike

Edit: So after looking into this further it seems like the plot formatting is just hanging this up. I profiled the function and came up with the following:

```
$by.self
            self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
Ephys v1.1.R#42      3.00    78.12       3.00     78.12
<no location>        0.50    13.02       0.50     13.02
Ephys v1.1.R#17      0.16     4.17       0.16      4.17
Ephys v1.1.R#30      0.16     4.17       0.16      4.17
Ephys v1.1.R#19      0.02     0.52       0.02      0.52

$by.total
                total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
Ephys v1.1.R#42       3.00     78.12      3.00    78.12
<no location>         0.50     13.02      0.50    13.02
Ephys v1.1.R#17       0.16      4.17      0.16     4.17
Ephys v1.1.R#30       0.16      4.17      0.16     4.17
Ephys v1.1.R#19       0.02      0.52      0.02     0.52

$by.line
                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
<no location>        0.50    13.02       0.50     13.02
Ephys v1.1.R#17      0.16     4.17       0.16      4.17
Ephys v1.1.R#19      0.02     0.52       0.02      0.52
Ephys v1.1.R#30      0.16     4.17       0.16      4.17
Ephys v1.1.R#42      3.00    78.12       3.00     78.12
```

Line #42 being grid.arrange(). I don't suppose there is much I can do on that front so I will consider the question answered. Still, the suggestions provided helped me get acclimated with the language a bit more so I appreciate all the help provided. Thanks!

Comment: In general if you have to loop though the elements of a list, use `lapply`, most times it allows you the same results of a for loop with an easier syntax and cheaper time costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[keep things in `data.frame`]**

Try wrapping your plot function first:

```
plot <- function(list_item) {
  ##subset of data containing only current and time info by looking for pA and Time patterns in variable name
  current<-subset(list_item, grepl('pA',list_item$variable)==TRUE|grepl('Time',list_item$variable)==TRUE) 
  ##create a plot of current vs time
  currentPlot<-ggplot(current, aes(Time..s.,value, group = variable)) + 
    geom_line() +
    xlim(c(0.2,0.4)) +
    xlab("") +
    ylim(c(-500,10000)) +
    ylab("Current (pA)") +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
          axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16, face='bold'))
  ##subset of data containing only voltage and time info by looking for mV and Time patterns in variable name
  voltage<-subset(list_item,grepl('mV',list_item$variable)==TRUE|grepl('Time',list_item$variable)==TRUE)
  ##create a plot of voltage vs time
  voltagePlot<-ggplot(voltage, aes(Time..s.,value, group = variable)) + 
    geom_line() +
    xlim(c(0.2,0.4)) +
    xlab("Time (s)") +
    ylab("Voltage (mV)") +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
          axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16, face='bold'))

  grid.arrange(currentPlot,voltagePlot, ncol=1)
}
```

Then call your plotting function with `lapply`:

```
traces <- function(list) {
    lapply(list, plot)
}
```

---

**[try `data.table`]**

If `data.frame` is the bottleneck here, I would suggest using `data.table`, which is a much faster implementation.

```
if (!require(data.table)) install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
plot <- function(list_item) {
    list_item <- data.table(list_item)
    current <- list_item[grepl('pA',variable)|grepl('Time',variable)]
    ....
    voltage <- list_item[grepl('mV',variable)|grepl('Time',variable)]
    ....
}
```

I do not have your data, so the code above might need minor tweaks.

Comment: Wrapping it instead of looping within the function did speed up the function slightly (~ 1 second). I will try the data.table and see if that helps this evening when I have a bit of time to sit down with it. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @MichaelYoung I forgot to mention, `grepl('pA',variable)==TRUE` is not necessary, because you don't want to compare `TRUE==TRUE`. Simply `grepl('pA',variable)` should suffice unless your data is really special. Let me know if that works so I can update my answer.

Comment: You are correct about the grepl. Thanks again! This is my first attempt at learning programming so I may misunderstand some of these commands. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The data.table approach doesn't seem to significantly change the speed of the program.

Comment: @MichaelYoung Maybe the `grepl` is slowing things down, because the code tries to scan `variable` for each row. If your data is consistent, you could extract the 2 characters from `variables` before hand and do all these. For example, `library(data.table) data[, id1:=(substr(variable, 11, 12)=='pA')][, id2:=(substr(variable, 1, 4)=='Time')]`, then you could potentially do something like `current <- list_item[id1|id2]`. However, that would require changing your data format before the list input, otherwise processing inside the function makes no difference.